# Why aren't the left and right papi lights written "in-line" in the lighting icons section of the Jeppesen chart?

Tags: aeronautical-charts, jeppesen, symbology, papi

Why aren't the left and right papi lights written "in-line" in the lighting icons section of the Jeppesen chart? Although there is REIL on other charts, it is written in line. Could this be because the papi lights are not aligned, or is it because the format is so coincidental at the time of writing? The icons that are out of alignment are not aligned for any of the LTBU Corlu Ataturk airport Jeppesen charts and I have marked them in yellow. In other airports, it is written aligned.

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: If you request, I can share the Jeppesen charts that I took the screenshots.

Comment: Looking at the physical lights, they are aligned.

Comment: Yes, maybe. But why is it not aligned in the symbol part?

Comment: I have no idea, I was only responding to this part: "Could this be because the papi lights are not aligned" ... they _are_ aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Jeppesen likely employs more than just one person to help prepare documents for publishing, and minor formatting details not crucial to compliance with a procedure are probably not specified in detail.

One person lined it up one way, another person lined it up a different way.

Comment: Thank you, sir.